# Why is the following map in Brill-Noether theory a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, covering-spaces

Let $$\phi:\{(X,f):\ X\text{ an algebraic curve of genus }g;f:X\to\mathbb{P}^1\text{ a morphism of degree $d$ that is single branched at $2g-2+2d$ different points} \}\to\mathbb{P}^{2g-2+2d}\setminus\Delta$$

Then my notes say $\phi$ is a covering map. Why is this so? My intuition is that $\phi$'s domain must have higher dimension because it appears to have a lot more of information than the branching loci $\mathbb{P}^{2g-2+2d}\setminus\Delta$

Comment: Can you describe the map carefully for me? What is $\phi(X,f)$?